# POSIXlt Changing Weekday In March 2014

Tags: r, date

I have an interesting problem arising.  I have minute by minute data for 2014 of certain stocks and I want to analyze Fridays only and am using the code below to do so.  It works great up until it gets to March.  All of a sudden, Thursdays are being given a weekday value of 5 from the 4th line of the code below.

For example, 3/14/14 was this past Friday, however, the code below is setting 3/13/14 as Friday even though it was a Thurs.

My guess is this has something to do with leap years, but it is only a guess.  Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

LNKD.csv, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xAKSwsHiEBNVpEbHJGMU9QYXc/edit?usp=sharing

LNKD Clean.csv, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xAKSwsHiEBVjBKcTM1VVg3aU0/edit?usp=sharing

```
data <- read.csv("LNKD.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$Up <- NULL
data$Down <- NULL
data$weekday <- as.POSIXlt(data$Date, format="%m/%d/%y")$wday
data <- subset(data, data$weekday==5)
write.csv(data, file="LNKD Clean.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your date format uses '%y' and not '%Y'.

'%y' is the two-digit year ('14') but '%Y' is the 4-digit year, and your years have 4 digits.

e.g.

```
as.POSIXlt('03/13/2014', format="%m/%d/%y")
# "2020-03-13"

as.POSIXlt('03/13/2014', format="%m/%d/%Y")
# "2014-03-13"
```

All your dates are being interpreted as the year 2020 because the first two digits of '2014' is '20' and '%y' means this is the year '2020'.

Comment: I thought it was the opposite.  Thank you for correcting me.